# Regex to replace links that have a certain class only with anchor text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a CSV file with a limited amount of HTML, only pure text (headings and paragraphs) and some links, so please don't suggest parsing instead of regex. :)

Here are two types of links that appear inside:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/1" class="linkclass" title="linktitle">anchor text 1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/2">anchor text 2</a>
```

Links with the class always have the same class - "linkclass" in this example. They also always have the same structure:

```
<a href="X" class="Y" title="Z">anchor text 1</a>
```

I need to select only the links that have a class "linkclass", remove them and leave only the anchor text. Other links should stay intact. The end result should be this:

```
anchor text 1
<a href="http://www.example.com/2">anchor text 2</a>
```

Here's the code I have used to select those links, but it also selects the anchor text:

```
<a href="(.*?)" class="linkclass" title="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>
```

How to adjust this regex to not select the anchor text?

Comment: No, it's pure HTML and I'd like to solve it with regex.

Comment: I see that you're using notepad++, I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
<a\b[^<]*class=['"]?linkclass["']?\b[^<]*?>([^<]*)<\/a>
```

Replace with `$1`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN3aZ6/2)

Comment: Great, that works. Is there a way to just select it without the anchor text and then replace it with nothing?

Comment: It depends on the language you are using. In .NET, it can be done easily.

Comment: It's HTML in Notepad++.

Comment: Ok,you still can do it the way I suggested. To remove `<a>` tags with nothing, you'd have to use a much more complicated regex, no use writing it, believe me.

Answer (score 1):

For notepad++ :

Hit <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd>
Choose <kbd>Replace</kbd>
Then <kbd>Regular Expression</kbd>  at the bottom

Find:

```
<a.*?linkclass.*?>(.*?)</a>
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

---

Result:

```
anchor text 1
<a href="http://www.example.com/2">anchor text 2</a>
```

Comment: If the link is in paragraph (e. g. <p>Text <a href...) then it will select the text from the beginning of paragraph. Adding "a" solves it "<a.*?linkclass.*?>(.*?)</a>"

Comment: I relied on the example you provided, I've updated the answer